# SpeechSynthesizer how to make the sound more human kind

Tags: forms, text-to-speech, speech, speechsynthesizer

I have a form application where I use the System voice to read words. However, it sounds robotic, how to make it more human-like?

I am using this:
using namespace System::Speech::Synthesis;

AND this:
SpeechSynthesizer^speaker=gcnew SpeechSynthesizer();
speaker->SpeakAsync(textBox1->Text);

The program works though, but I want it to sound like a human.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Speech.Synthesis` is very VERY old (15+ years old). Thus, it sounds robotic.

You could try using the latest speech platform from Microsoft. NOTE: I worked on `System.Speech` and on this latest speech platform (Cognitive Services Speech). You can find samples and instructions on how to use this platform here: https://aka.ms/speech/sdk.

Additionally, if you'd like to hear what these voices sound like, you can listen to samples of them here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/

--robch